# What is the .default scope for graph.microsoft.com

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, access-token

I can use a service principal to get an access-token from https://graph.microsoft.com but when I try to get a token for https://graph.microsoft.com/.default I get the following error.

What is possible impact if my token was issued without this scope?

> Get Token request returned http error: 400 and server response:
> {
> "error": "invalid_resource",
> "error_description": "AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://graph.microsoft.com/.default was not found in the tenant named 4c000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
>
> Trace ID: 00-00-00-00000
> Correlation ID: 00-00-00-000
> Timestamp: 2020-08-06 00:17:31Z
>
> "error_codes": [ 500011 ],
> "timestamp": "2020-08-06 00:17:31Z",
> "trace_id": "d301a1cb-8feb-44e0-8b04-e463dd8d5b00",
> "correlation_id": "92947479-d924-49fd-8e29-1d7cbe70d289",
> "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=500011"
> }

Comment: Which authentication flow are you using?

Comment: How did you request the token and is it convenient to provide screenshots? After my test, if there is no "scope" parameter, the token cannot be requested. It looks like this: 
`https//graph.microsoft.com/scope`.

Comment: I am using Azure cli - using the command [az account get-access-token --resource https://graph.microsoft.com] I guess it will be client credentials flow because I have used [az login --service-principal --username CLIENTID --password [CLINESECRET] --tenant [tenantID] before requesting this token (the editor is hiding the https before graph.microsoft.com)

Comment: Hi, do you have a chance to look into my answer? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you use the `v1.0` endpoint to get the access token. It generally uses `Resource` as the request parameter.

For v1.0 endpoints, there is generally no need to use the `/.default` scope,you need to add the `/.default` scope only when you use the `v2.0` endpoint to get the token.

So you can use this token with confidence,this has no impact.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In case anybody else wonders what the `/.default` scope is all about you can check out this [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#the-default-scope):

> The /.default scope is built in for every application that refers to the static list of permissions configured on the application registration.

So basically, the `/.default` scope infers the permissions from the according application.

Comment: link provided is link to a login page